# Creating a basic stack overflow using IDA

Tags: c, security, stack-overflow, ida

This program is running with root privileges on my machine and I need to perform a Stack overflow attack on the following code and get root privileges:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

void sha256(char *string, char outputBuffer[65])
{
    unsigned char hash[SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    int i = 0;
    SHA256_CTX sha256;
    SHA256_Init(&sha256);
    SHA256_Update(&sha256, string, strlen(string));
    SHA256_Final(hash, &sha256);

    for(i = 0; i < SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        sprintf(outputBuffer + (i * 2), "%02x", hash[i]);
    }
    outputBuffer[64] = 0;
}

int password_check(char *userpass)
{
    char text[20] = "thisisasalt";
    unsigned int password_match = 0;
    char output[65] = { 0, };
    // >>> hashlib.sha256("Hello, world!").hexdigest()
    char pass[] = "315f5bdb76d078c43b8ac0064e4a0164612b1fce77c869345bfc94c75894edd3"; 

    text[0] = 'a';
    text[1] = 't';
    text[2] = 'j';
    text[3] = '5';
    text[4] = '3';
    text[5] = 'k';
    text[6] = '$';
    text[7] = 'g';
    text[8] = 'f';
    text[9] = '[';
    text[10] = ']';
    text[11] = '\0';
    strcat(text, userpass);
    sha256(text, output);

    if (strcmp(output, pass) == 0)
    {
        password_match = 1;
    }

    return (password_match == 1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <pass> <command>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    if (strlen((const char *) argv[1]) > 10)
    {
        printf("Error: pasword too long\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (password_check(argv[1]))
    {
        printf("Running command as root: %s\n", argv[2]);
        setuid(0);
        setgid(0);
        system(argv[2]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Authentication failed! This activity will be logged!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So I try to analyse the program with IDA and I see the text segment going from the lower addresses to the higher addresses, higher than that I see the data and then the bss and finally external commands.

Now as far as I know the stack should be just above that, but I'm not certain how to view it, how exactly am I supposed to view the stack in order to know what I'm writing on? (Do I even need it or am I completely clueless?)

Second question is considering the length of the input, how do i get around this check in the code:

```
if (strlen((const char *) argv[1]) > 10)
    {
        printf("Error: pasword too long\n");
        exit(1);
    }
```

Can I somehow give the string to the program by reference? If so how do I do it? (Again, hoping I'm not completely clueless)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now as far as I know the stack should be just above that, but I'm not certain how to view it, how exactly am I supposed to view the stack in order to know what I'm writing on? (Do I even need it or am I completely clueless?)

The stack location varies all the time - you need to look at the value of the `ESP`/`RSP` register, its value is the current address of the top of the stack. Typically, variable addressing will be based on `EBP` rather then `ESP`, but they both will point to the same general area of memory.

During analysis, IDA sets up a stack frame for each function, which acts much like a `struct` - you can define variables with types and names in it. This frame is summarized at the top of the function: [image: stack summary view]
Double-clicking it or any local variable in the function body will open a more detailed window. That's as good as you can get without actually running your program in a debugger.

You can see that `text` is right next to `password_match`, and judging from the addresses, there are `0x14` bytes allocated for `text`, as one would expect. However, *this is not guaranteed* and the compiler can freely shuffle the variables around, pad them or optimize them into registers.

> Second question is considering the length of the input, how do i get around this check in the code:
>
> ```
> if (strlen((const char *) argv[1]) > 10)
> {
>     printf("Error: pasword too long\n");
>     exit(1);
> }
> ```

You don't need to get around this check, it's already broken enough. There's an off-by-one error.

Stop reading here if you want to figure out the overflow yourself.

---

> The valid range of indices for `text` spans from `text[0]` through `text[19]`. In the code, user input is written to the memory area starting at `text[11]`. The maximum input length allowed by the `strlen` check is 10 symbols + the NULL terminator. Unfortunately, that means `text[19]` contains the 9th user-entered symbol, and the 10th symbol + the terminator overflow into adjacent memory space. Under certain circumstances, that allows you to overwrite the least significant byte of `password_match` with an arbitrary value, and the second least significant byte with a `0`.
>  Your function accepts the password if `password_match` equals `1`, which means the 10th character in your password needs to be `'\x01'` (note that this is not the same character as `'1'`).

Here are two screenshots from IDA running as a debugger. `text` is highlighted in yellow, `password_match` is in green.

The password I entered was `123456789\x01`.

1. Stack before user entered password is `strcat`'d into `text`.
   [image: stack variables before overflow]
2. Stack after `strcat`. Notice that `password_match` changed.
   [image: stack variables after overflow]

Comment: wow man thank you so much, i figured some of it out alone including where the overflow was but i was sure i was writing over the return address and not over password!, it works great, thank you!